# cargar side menu al iniciar sesion

Tags: angular, ionic, ionic3

Tengo una app en ionic con side menu y con lazy loadings , estoy llenando el side menu desde un web service dependiendo del usuario; Pasando el login en el app.html tengo esta funcion

```
<ion-menu [content]="content" (ionOpen)="menuOpened()">
```

esa funcion menuOpened() hace la llamada a un provider que hace la peticion al web service y retorna el json del menu , nuevamente si se genera bien :esta es la funcion

```
menuOpened(){

if (this.pages.length <= 0  ) {
  this.menuProvider.getSideMenus().then((resp)=>{
    console.log("si entro");
    this.pages = resp;
    console.log(this.pages);
  });

} else{
  console.log("blablabla");


 }
}
```

Mi duda o problema aqui es que esa funcion hace al abrir el menu y hace la peticion pero no carga el menu , debo cerrarlo y volver a abrirlo y ya me aparece el menu dinamico ,

hay alguna forma de llamar esa funcion que esta en el app.component.ts desde el constructor de mi HomePage una vez que pase el login , para que se genere de primeras el menu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para esto debes utilizar [Eventos](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/api/util/Events/), es algo fácil de implementar, en sí lo que haces es suscribirte a un evento y lo puedes disparar desde cualquier parte de tu aplicación.

Suscribirse a un evento:

```
this.events.subscribe('user:created', () => {
        // Tu logica de cuando mandes a llamarlo
        // Deberia obtener dinamicamte la información del menú
      });
```

Activar el evento desde cualquier parte de la App(Ej: Luego del Login):

```
this.events.publish('user:created');
```

Comment: muchas gracias si logre hacerlo de esa manera , en mi desesperacion encontre un post y me sirvio muchisimo , aun asi muchas gracias

Comment: Seria bueno que compartieras el post que te ayudó a resolver, asi puedes ayudar a mas personas que tengan este problema, Saludos. @debekmendoza

Comment: ya no encontre el post pero consumi un web service desde en un provider en una funcion, esa la mando a llamar en el app.component y luego hago referencia a la misma desde el app.html y muestro los datos con recorriendo la respuesta con un ngfor , si encuentro el post lo pondre aqui